# Populating google map with array of circle objects created from Fusion Table data

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I know I am overlooking/not considering something elementary, but I don't know what I don't know...

Trying to use Fusion Tables to populate an array of Google Maps API circle objects and place them on a map.

Currently I am able to hard-code the array like so:

```
citymap['Dane'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.10599621690524, -89.38682556152344),
    population: 5000000
};
```

...and place them on a [map](http://jsfiddle.net/chrislkeller/NvBXR/16/).

And I am able to return JSON from the Fusion Tables, loop through and create what I think is an array and [display it](http://jsfiddle.net/chrislkeller/x7DeR/4/), but I can't make the circle objects appear.

Any advice on what I need to google/learn would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using the new Trusted Tester API to generate Polygons to display on the map:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/mouseover_map_styles

The logic should be similar, but instead of a Polygon, you would create a Circle:

```
new google.maps.Circle({
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(<lat>, <lng>),
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  map: map,
  radius: <radius>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check out the [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle) class; it provides a simple way to create circular shapes and place them on the map. Ok, so I see you've already found the shape class, so you are good there.

I think your problem is that you are turning everything into strings in your processing loop:

```
citymap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.table.rows.length; i++) {
    citymap += 'citymap[\'' + data.table.rows[i][0] + '\'] = {' +
        'center: new google.maps.LatLng(' + data.table.rows[i][1] + '),' +
           'population: 2842518};';
}
```

I think you want code that looks more like this:

```
citymap = new Array();
for ( var i = 0; i < data.table.rows.length; i++ ) {
    var circleData = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( data.table.rows[i][1] );
        position: 2842518
    }
    citymap.push( circleData );
}
```

I realize I have left some other bit of data out, but you get the idea. I believe your primary problem was that you were stringifying the code.